# Is it possible to define a class property with predefined string literal types in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I’m trying to achieve the following in Typescript, but keep getting a compilation error:

```
const AUDIENCE_ALL_COMPANY = 'all_company'
const AUDIENCE_SITE = 'site'
const AUDIENCE_DEPARTMENT = 'department'

export class Post {
  readonly audienceType: AUDIENCE_ALL_COMPANY | AUDIENCE_SITE | AUDIENCE_DEPARTMENT

   ...
}
```

Is it possible to do achieve my goal here in Typescript?

Comment: Ok... what's the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those constants are all variables with values that happen to be strings. You're trying to use them as types.  They're not types, so define it.

```
const AUDIENCE_ALL_COMPANY = 'all_company';
const AUDIENCE_SITE = 'site';
const AUDIENCE_DEPARTMENT = 'department';

type AUDIENCE_ALL_COMPANY = typeof AUDIENCE_ALL_COMPANY;
type AUDIENCE_SITE = typeof AUDIENCE_SITE;
type AUDIENCE_DEPARTMENT = typeof AUDIENCE_DEPARTMENT;

export class Post {
    readonly audienceType: AUDIENCE_ALL_COMPANY | AUDIENCE_SITE | AUDIENCE_DEPARTMENT;
}
```